# Airflow Rendered Template changes when task starts running?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, kubernetespodoperator

I'm having a very weird airflow bug.

### Problem

I have a dag that has a `bash operator` as step 1 and a `KubernetesPodOperator` as step 2. The issue is regarding the `KubernetesPodOperator`. Basically, I was giving the task image `X` for quite some time, I recently changed the image the task is receiving to `Y`.
The issue I'm having is within `TaskInstanceDetails` the image is correct: `Y`. However, in the Rendered Template, the image starts correct `X`, however, as soon as the task starts running, it changes the image to `Y`.

I know this is very vague, I can't provide a whole lot more, but I'm just more looking for possibilities of things that could be happening, as I'm out of ideas.

### What I've Tried

- Delete Serialized Dags from DB
- Delete Rendered Task Details from DB
- Airflow db reset
- Airflow db init (After nuking the whole thing)
- Deleting the EC2 nodes and trying with new ones

##### EDIT

So, I tried runnning `airflow tasks render dag_id task_id execution_date` and the result here is image `X` !! Image `Y` is only superimposed on dag runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here in case anyone runs into this issue. Very simple fix... I carelessly had a different image name for the workers to be run with on the kubernetes_pod_template file. Changing that solved the issue.